# How do I append different courses in to each classrooms?

Tags: python

I want  to append different courses into two different classrooms, however it keeps adding the same courses to both of the classrooms.
This is my AddCourse function

## Edited

I modified my code according to your suggestions.

```
class Classroom:
    """I omitted part of the class for brevity"""
    def __init__(self, Seed = None, ClassroomId = None, FirstCourseStartTime = None, LastCourseEndTime = None, CourseList = [], ProfessorList = []):
        self.setFirstCourseStartTime(FirstCourseStartTime)
        self.setLastCourseEndTime(LastCourseEndTime)
        self.setCourseList(CourseList)
        self.setProfessorList(ProfessorList)
        self.setSeed(Seed)
        self.setClassroomId(ClassroomId)
    def addCourse(self, Course):
        self.CourseList.append(Course)
    def setCourseList(self, List):
        self.CourseList = List
#the statements below are from a different file to run the code/class above    
Classroom1 = Classroom(Seed = os.urandom(1024/8), FirstCourseStartTime = 8, LastCourseEndTime = 19.75)
Classroom2 = Classroom(Seed = os.urandom(1024/8), FirstCourseStartTime = 8, LastCourseEndTime = 19.75)
# Adding the courses to the classrooms
Classroom1.addCourse(Course0)
Classroom1.addCourse(Course1)
Classroom1.addCourse(Course2)
Classroom1.addCourse(Course3)
Classroom1.addCourse(Course4)
Classroom1.addCourse(Course5)
Classroom1.addCourse(Course6)
Classroom1.addCourse(Course7)
Classroom2.addCourse(Course8)
Classroom2.addCourse(Course9)
Classroom2.addCourse(Course10)
Classroom2.addCourse(Course11)
Classroom2.addCourse(Course12)
Classroom2.addCourse(Course13)
Classroom2.addCourse(Course14)
Classroom2.addCourse(Course15)
```

Comment: How to you create your "Course" instances? Also, TitleCase is usually reserved for class names. So this can make it hard to see what is actually an instance or a method call vs a Class

Comment: There's a programming rule of thumb that says that if you find yourself repeating the same instruction 3 or more times, you should use a loop instead.

Comment: You omitted the part with the bug for "brevity", yet included 16 calls to the same method to compensate for the brevity? -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your issue is that all instances of your class are dealing with the same list, since you are declaring it only once.

Here's an example of your problem, without all the extra stuff that doesn't matter:

```
class Classroom(object):

    def __init__(self, course_list=[]):
        self.course_list = course_list

    def add_course(self, course):
        self.course_list.append(course)
```

When we use it, we see the behavior you described:

```
c1 = Classroom()
c2 = Classroom()

c1.add_course('ENG 101')
c2.add_course('MATH 101')

print c1.course_list
print c2.course_list
```

Prints:

```
['ENG 101', 'MATH 101']
['ENG 101', 'MATH 101']
```

To show that this is the same list, we can print the `id` of each instance's list:

```
print id(c1.course_list)
print id(c2.course_list)
```

For me, this outputs this (though it likely different each time):

```
4299912760
4299912760
```

**The problem line for you is `course_list=[]` in `__init__`'s param list.**  You're defining the list there, then likely not copying it anywhere else.  This means whenever you append to the list, it's always the same list you are appending to.  It's important to understand that, in python, the method `def` line (not the body, obviously), is only run once, not every time you create a new instance (or run the function, for that matter).

Here's a corrected version.  Instead of defaulting to `[]`, you should most always default to `None` then handle setting it as a list of nothing was given.

```
class Classroom2(object):

    def __init__(self, course_list=None):
        self.course_list = course_list or []

    def add_course(self, course):
        self.course_list.append(course)


c1 = Classroom2()
c2 = Classroom2()

c1.add_course('ENG 101')
c2.add_course('MATH 101')

print c1.course_list
print c2.course_list
```

Now this prints as expected:

```
['ENG 101']
['MATH 101']
```

Answer (score 3):

It would really help if you gave your class definition.

At a guess, you have defined .CourseList as a class variable rather than an object variable.

Also, check out the [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) formatting guidelines; methods should be `.like_this`, not `.LikeThis`!

```
class Classroom(object):
    courses = []     # class variable - all instances share the same list

    def __init__(self):
        self.courses = []    # object variable - each instance has its own
```

**Edit:** ok; now let's see your definition for `.setCourseList()`...

Comment: I think your suggestion about having added it as a class attribute is probably right. Also you should mention that object instances/attributes should probably be lowercase too

Comment: I don't have any class variables.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the `extend` method ? (instead of `append`)

You can add several values to a list like this:

```
a = [1,2,3]
a.extend([4,5,6])
print a // [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

(Altough i'm not sure i've understood what you wanted to do ...)

Comment: Its probably what Hugh suggested, about the class attribute vs instance attribute

Comment: I am not looking for extend method, however I am trying to add first seven courses to classroom1 and course eight through 15 to classroom 2.